# poincare series of subsets of affine weyl groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

It is known that if A is subset of reflection subgroup of an affine coxeter group W then the poincare series of minimal length coset representatives of A is a rational function.From this fact is it true that poincare series of A itself is a rational function with respect to the length function Of W?